# Does Firebase Test Lab support XCUITests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-test-lab

Does Firebase Test Lab support XCUITests in Swift and Objective-C?  The documentation mentions XCTest but not XCUITest.

Also interested if this Firebase Test Lab related tool supports XCUITests:
https://github.com/TestArmada/flank

Comment: Many parts of Firebase comes with no or limited UI of their own. What specific part of Firebase are you looking to use in your application, and what about that integration are you looking to test?

Comment: Sorry I edited my question because my question is specific to Firebase Test Lab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Test Lab can run both XCTest and XCUITest.
Yes, tests or the app can be in Swift or Objective-C.

For Flank, the test runner, it should not matter what type of test you are running.

Comment: Hi @Maik, In my project I have both XCTest and XCUITest but the test is only running on XCTest. I am not sure why it's not running upon XCUITest. Could you please help me on this.